# How to successfully "Generate a Notification Key on the Client" with GCM?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm following the below instructions, but the response is always HTTP 401 Unauthorized. I have verified that the ID token, registration ID, and project ID (number) are all valid. Unfortunately the response does not provide a detailed reason.

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html#gen-client

What is necessary to receive an HTTP 200 response with the notification_key? I'm wondering if the documentation is missing an important detail or if there is a known issue with the service. Otherwise GCM and the Google auth token are working fine for me.

Here is a redacted net log. Does the request require any other headers or JSON fields that are not specified in the documentation?

```
---> HTTP POST https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/googlenotification
project_id: {project-number}
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
{"id_token":"{long-auth-token}",
"notification_key_name":"{unique-name}",
"operation":"add",
"registration_ids":["{reg-id}"]}

<--- HTTP 401 https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/googlenotification
```

Edit: I'm suspicious that the `id_token` field is not being used by the service.  If I remove any other field, the response is `{"error":"Missing \"{field-name}\" field"}`.  But it doesn't return a similar response when `id_token` is missing.

Comment: I've got the same problem, have you found a solution?

Comment: No, I retried it on and off through the year, but always had the same problem.  And after getting no response from DevRel, I've given up on it.

Comment: Looks like notification_key_name needs to be the email of the user that gets your id_token, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34298106/3983628).

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a new project with a new API key and see if you are still getting 401 error. And make sure you have 'Any IP allowed' not just IPv4 0.0.0.0/0.

Comment: In this case I don't believe an API key is involved.  My understanding is that the service would authenticate by checking if the `id_token` was generated for the referenced `project_id`.  I have tried adding an `Authorization: key=API_KEY` header, as is required in the Generate a Notification Key on the Server method, but this did not help.  I have also verified that my API key has "Any IP allowed".